# delete query not working in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I tried everything I could find online to get it to work, I tried casting $employeeid to int after retrieving it from the link (even though they say mysql does it for you), i tried using nested single quotes, escape quotes... the print line happens to work, and employeeid shows up as a number in the hyperlink when delete is clicked, but it never deletes. what could I be doing wrong?

also, I could've sworn the onclick="return confirm("")" in the hyperlink was supposed to cause a pop up to appear, but it didnt, am I forgetting something here as well or is it a syntax issue?

this is my php link that calls it:

```
<td><a href='employ.php?delete=yes&employeeid=$employeeid onclick=\"return confirm(\"Are you sure\")\"'>Delete</a></td>
```

and this is the code section that is supposed to handle it:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $temp = $_GET['$employeeid'];
    print "teseting delete<br><br>";
    $query = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE employeeid = ".$temp;
    mysqli_query($link, $query); //link query to database
    print "Employee Updated"; // print confirmation

}
```

Comment: have you checked with `print_r($_GET);` at the top to confirm that the data passes??

Comment: Replace `$temp = $_GET['$employeeid'];` with `$employeeid = $_GET['employeeid'];` then do `WHERE employeeid = ".$employeeid;`

Comment: wowwwwwww this is why i hate coding late at night @_@ i spend all night thinking i dont understand the concepts and its dumbass syntax >.<

Comment: @JL Has my comment above fixed the problem?

Comment: well everyone sorta answered the problem at the same time lol.

Comment: @JL That's good. Well, pick the answer below that does fix it to close the question, unless you want me to make my comment an answer. However, some did address the `href` issue. I think `Johnroe`'s is the one that covers all the bases ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $temp = $_GET['employeeid']; <<=== remove the $ sign
    print "teseting delete<br><br>";
    $query = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE employeeid = ".$temp;
    mysqli_query($link, $query); //link query to database
    print "Employee Updated"; // print confirmation
}
```

And on your link:

```
<td>
     <a href="employ.php?delete=yes&employeeid=$employeeid" onclick= 'return confirm("Are you sure")'>Delete</a>
</td>
```

Take note on the `href` attribute, it is enclosed in double quotes since you are putting PHP variables in your link

Comment: awesome it really is too late for me to be doing all this coding >.< or maybe i just need more php practice

Comment: Everybody has gone to that 'scratch-your-head' stage when committing mistakes. Just continue practicing, as we all programmers do. :)

Answer (score 2):

`href` and`onclick` are separate attributes, you have them combined into one.

```
<td><a href='employ.php?delete=yes&employeeid=$employeeid' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure\")'>Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: thanks i hate it when I'm scratching my head forever over that kinda thing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Variable in GET Method that you are using `$employeeid`, May be it is `employeeid`

```
$temp = $_GET['employeeid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

check your table name , field name ,user permission in mysql and relation with other table . if u use foreign key of employeeId in another table then also you not able to delete

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM employees WHERE employeeid ='$temp'");
```

Comment: Just a quick FYI: In `mysqli_`, the DB connection comes first, not last. See `Johnroe`'s answer, that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope this may helpful

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $temp = $_GET['employeeid']; 
    print "teseting delete<br><br>";
    $query = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE employeeid = ".$temp;
    mysqli_query($link, $query); //link query to database
    print "Employee Updated"; // print confirmation
}
<td><a href="test.php?delete=yes&employeeid=<?=$employeeid;?>" onclick= 'return confirm("Are you sure")'>Delete</a></td>
```